# Cannot reinstall iPhoto from App Store in Lion

Tags: macos, applications, install, mac-appstore, photos.app

My company recently upgraded my laptop to OS X Lion and was pre-installed with iPhoto purchased under a different Apple ID. I have my own purchased version so wanted to update the app, but it asked for the other user's password.

So I decided to uninstall the app using Launchpad and try downloading it again. However, when I go to it in the Mac App Store, the button now says "ACCEPT" and when I click on it, I get this message:

> These apps cannot be accepted on this computer.
>   Future updates of these apps can be found through Software Update.

What can I do to get iPhoto to download again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and finally found the following solution on the [apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3491217?start=0&tstart=0) that worked for me:

1. Launch App Store
2. Click the "Purchases" tab (the price-tag icon at the top of the App Store window)
3. Find iMovie in the list
4. Click its "INSTALL" button

Comment: Nice one thanks! I forgot to return here to answer the question... After contacting Apple email support, they told me to do this. I can't believe I missed the Purchases tab! Having said that, it seems a bit silly that the App Store doesn't suggest you do this or do it automatically itself!